# systemd can't find file but it is there

Tags: systemd

Here is my systemd error:
Apr 21 06:26:03 web-vm1 systemd[967]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /sw/service-5.0/freeswitch-notify/freeswitch-notify-366428/etc/rc.d/init.d/freeswitch-notify.rc: No such file or directory

However:
ls -l /sw/service-5.0/freeswitch-notify/freeswitch-notify-366428/etc/rc.d/init.d/freeswitch-notify.rc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4844 Apr 22 17:35 /sw/service-5.0/freeswitch-notify/freeswitch-notify-366428/etc/rc.d/init.d/freeswitch-notify.rc

The file works fine if run by hand. This used to work. /sw is an NFS mount. Was something added to make systemd not look at remote filesystems?

Comment: Are you sure the filesystem gets mounted before `systemd` tries to reach the file? Have you taken care of this dependency?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to start above by hand and it still fails, even though the file is there.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084611/what-does-sh-executable-pathnot-found-mean

Comment: It's a shell script that calls /bin/bash and, as above is 755. However, the script copies a config file into /etc/ld.so.conf.d and runs ldconfig. Is it possible that this error is because something in the script isn't running, and it's not picking up the ldconfig changes?

Comment: I think there's something else going on. I edited ExecStart to change the path, and ran systemctl daemon-reload. No changes then I realized my logs were from yesterday. Turned out at boot, the mount point was not available. I had to run stop, then start to clear cache or something.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that something gets cached, and you have to stop first, even if it isn't running.

Comment: Holy, cost me an hour to find out this